# Intellij Flutter - Import via Alt+Enter not working

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

My team members and me often face the problem in Intellij that we cannot **import some classes via Alt+Enter** because Intellij hasn't indexed them successfully.

#### Our set up

We have different Flutter projects which belong and work together.

ProjectFolder:

- *our_project/customer_app*
- *our_project/provider_app*
- *our_project/server_app*
- *our_project/model_app*

Some of these projects have dependencies to other projects which are declared in the **pubspec.yaml** file.

#### Problem

E.g. the *customer_app* has a dependency to the *model_app*.
Now we add this new class in model_app such as **class MyModel**.

Later in the process we want to use **MyModel** inside of the *customer_app*.
If we type something like **MyModel()** and try to press **Alt+Enter** it doesn't find the class immediately. (it works miracously only sometimes)

What we have to do then is to copy the path of **MyModel** and do the import manually. Which is often time consuming.

We even tried to run *flutter packages get* which also doesn't help to find this import of **MyModel**. Ideally we want that Intellij find the import automatically by indexing it without copying the path out of the other project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and planned to be fixed eventually.

You can upvote https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25820

Comment: Great! Thank you, Günter.